# Ember acceptance testing - async side effects error

Tags: ember.js, qunit, acceptance-testing, ember-testing

Attempting to run acceptance tests in Ember:

```
test('successful login', (assert) => {

  Ember.run(() => {
    visit('/signin');
    fillIn('#email', 'validemail@server.com');
    fillIn('#password', 'password');
    click(':submit');

    andThen(function() {
      assert.equal(currentURL(), '/');
    });
  });
});
```

Occasionally (and seemingly randomly) yields the error:

"Global error: Error: Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run..."

I was able to get a working version:

```
test('successful login', (assert) => {
  const done = assert.async();

  Ember.run(() => {
    visit('/signin').then(() => {
      fillIn('#email', 'isaac@silverorange.com').then(() => {
        fillIn('#password', 'keen').then(() => {
          click(':submit').then(() => {
            assert.equal(currentURL(), '/');
            done();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

However, if I include a second test making use of the same route (for an unsuccessful login), one of them almost always ends up with the error listed above.

I am wondering what I am not understanding about the run-loop, Ember.run, and how to test with async behavior.  Any help or pointers towards a good resource would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you wrapping everything in `Ember.run`? That is not needed and likely the cause of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/testing/acceptance/#toc_asynchronous-helpers), your code should be like this:

```
test('successful login', (assert) => {
  visit('/signin');
  fillIn('#email', 'validemail@server.com');
  fillIn('#password', 'password');
  click(':submit');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/');
  });
});
```

You don't need to add an `Ember.run` to your cases.

Comment: Removing the `Ember.run` gave the same error : ` Error: Assertion Failed: You have turned on ...`

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly, this problem occurs when you're doing something (asynchronously) in your application that isn't properly wrapped for Ember (by wrapped I mean executed inside the Ember run loop).

## Most common causes

1. You attached an event handler to the DOM, either directly or with jQuery without wrapping interaction with the Ember application in Ember.run()
2. You executed a XHR (asynchronous), either directly or with jQuery without wrapping interaction with the Ember application inside the callback in Ember.run()

## Generic fix

When you cause code execution that interacts with your application outside the runloop (XHR callback or event handlers) wrap that code with Ember.run().

Events:

```
Ember.$('div').on('mouseover',function() {
    Ember.run(function() {
       // Interaction with application
    });
});
```

XHR/Ajax:

```
Ember.$.ajax({
    success: function() {
        Ember.run(function() {
           // Interaction with application
        });
    }
});
```

## Best practices

1. When working with DOM events:

   - Use component event handling (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/handling-events/)
   - Use template actions (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/templates/actions/)
2. When you want to do AJAX/XHR use ember-ajax (https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax)